# How to launch local Unity API Reference from MonoDevelop

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

In MonoDevelop, Ctrl+' (not F1) brings the Unity API Reference (help) from http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/... 
instead of reading it from local copy of the Unity API. 
How can I make it consistently open the local documentation?

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/30436/launching-local-unity-api-reference-from-monodevel.html

Comment: Thanks. I have read this answer, but I still don't konw how to launch local Unity API Reference from MonoDevelop

Comment: have you find a pretty ways?China area redirect link to `unity3d.com/cn/...` but the address is 404

Comment: @LoranceChen 你如何解决的~？ is this problem fixed?

Comment: @zippo, hi, I'm use a redirect plugin on browser.See answer below, besides, have you test the latest version (2017.1)?

Comment: @LoranceChen thanks for your reply, I'm using the latest version. And the redirect plugin doesn't work for me. Maybe i use it in a incorrect way.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

<strike>If you use **Firefox**</strike>, you can use [Redirector](http://einaregilsson.com/redirector/) to redirect to your local documentation. Install the addon, and open the options. (*Ctrl+Shift+A > Extensions > Redirector > Options*)

Then use these values (or similar, depending on the location of your local documentation):

- Description: `Unity Documentation` (or whatever you'd like)
- Example URL: `http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=Transform` (Or any other search query. Used to preview what the link will redirect to. This is optional.)
- Include Pattern: `http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/*` Note that I use `unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/...`, because that is the URL opened by MonoDevelop, which is then redirected to `docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/...`
- Redirect To: `file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Unity/Editor/Data/Documentation/html/en/ScriptReference/$1` If Unity is not installed on the C drive or if you use a different OS, you're gonna have to find out what the local URL looks like, and replace everything to the right of `/ScriptReference/` with `$1`. (`/ScriptReference/index.html` to `/ScriptReference/$1`)
- Pattern Type: `Wildcard`
- You can leave all other fields as they are.

Now anytime you press the shortcut, you will automatically be redirected to your local API reference instead of the online one. I've also tested it without internet connection. Unfortunately, the addon is only available for Mozilla Firefox, and I haven't succeeded in doing that with other tools for different browsers yet.

Edit: Redirector is now also available for Chrome and Opera, according to [the author's website](http://einaregilsson.com/redirector/).

Comment: Quick heads up, Redirector does not seem to work when Firefox is using the "multi-process" mode.

Comment: in my case it does not work at all. the notification shows that the page is redirecting but it does nothing. not loading the page, not changing the url. nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Unity's Mono AddIn searches at fixed paths for local documentation and uses the online one, if it cannot be found there. The standard installation obviously uses slightly different paths. To fix this for many cases, you can create the following symbolic links (as admin).

For Mac create:

```
for name in $(ls /Applications/Unity/Documentation/en/); do ln -s  /Applications/Unity/Documentation/en/$name/   /Applications/Unity/Documentation/$name; done
```

On Windows use:

```
mkdir "c:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Documentation\Documentation"
mklink /D "c:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Documentation\Documentation\ScriptReference" "c:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Documentation\en\ScriptReference\"
...
```

Nice effect: Unity's type documentation does open faster and also offline from Mono via standard ctrl+' in many cases, especially if you mark the full type. Sadly it still goes to the online version, if the search function is needed in cases where there is no direct hit.